# HTML5 Video Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm creating a website that uses HTML5, positioned divs and a decision tree to create what basically amounts to a game.

My question is, what are the benefits of the following solutions:

Having a single large video where I set times to navigate and loop certain sections?

OR

Many small videos that swap out with one another and loop using the `onended` event?

Comment: Thanks for closing my question guys, any tips on how to edit it so that it fits within your format?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, both ways are technically possible.

I would suggest to use the latter method, as visitors tend to lose interest if they found the video is too long. Also, assumed download play is used instead of streaming, small video requires less bandwidth and can enjoy faster preload time.